# How to pick file spacific extention (.anon) file and load in app in android 11+ with out MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android

Hi i have a app that use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to work fine with Android 11+ to Import and Export Config files with .anon extention. But google play dosn't accept MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to upload app update.

can someone guide me how can alternativily can import file without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, which changes i have to do to do so.

here's ConfigImportFileActivity.java that is used to list and import .anon files also can delete .anon files

```
package com.agn.injector.activities;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
import static android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION;
import static android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import com.agn.injector.R;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.agn.injector.adapter.ManagerFilesAdapter;
import com.agn.injector.logger.SkStatus;
import com.agn.injector.MainActivity;
import com.agn.injector.fragments.RequestPermissionDialogFragment;
import com.agn.injector.config.ConfigParser;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

import com.agn.injector.config.Settings;

public class ConfigImportFileActivity extends BaseActivity implements ManagerFilesAdapter.OnItemClickListener, RequestPermissionDialogFragment.RequestPermissionListener {
    private static final String RESTORE_CURRENT_PATH = "restoreCurrentPath";
    private static final String HOME_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String BACK_DIR = "../";
    
    private RecyclerView rvManagerList;
    private ManagerFilesAdapter adapter;
    
    private List<ManagerFilesAdapter.ManagerItem> folderList;
    private List<ManagerFilesAdapter.ManagerItem> fileList;
    private String currentPath;
    private File backDir;
    private String pathAbertoPeloInicio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        if (SkStatus.isTunnelActive()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_tunnel_service_execution, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        
        // Get the intent that started this activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String scheme = intent.getScheme();
        
        // Figure out what to do based on the intent type
        if (scheme != null && (scheme.equals("file") || scheme.equals("content"))) {
            // mostra loading bonitinho
            setContentView(R.layout.launchvpn);
            
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            
            File file = new File(data.getPath());

            String file_extensao = getExtension(file);
            if (file_extensao != null && file_extensao.equals(ConfigParser.FILE_EXTENSAO)) {
                
                try {
                    importarConfigInputFile(getContentResolver()
                        .openInputStream(data));
                } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_file_config_incompatible,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_file_config_incompatible,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            
            finish();
            return;
        }
        
        // set Views
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_config_import);
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
        rvManagerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMain_ManagerList);
        setToolbar();
        
        // Para Android 6.0 Marshmallow e superior
        if (SDK_INT >= 23 && !permissionGranted()) {
            requestPermissionInfo(); // Para Android 5.1 Lollipop e inferior
            return;
        }
        
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentPath = savedInstanceState.getString(RESTORE_CURRENT_PATH);
            fileManager(currentPath);
        } else {
            //fileManager(HOME_PATH);
            startMainListManager();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(RESTORE_CURRENT_PATH, currentPath);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    // onClickPositiveButton na caixa de diálogo para confirmar permissões
    @Override
    public void onClickRequestPermissionDialog(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ConfigImportFileActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    
    /**
    * ItemListener implementação
    */
    
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        File file = new File(folderList.get(position).getDirPath());
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            fileManager(folderList.get(position).getDirPath());
        } else {
            // Tratamento para arquivos
            String file_extensao = getExtension(file);
            if (file_extensao != null && file_extensao.equals(ConfigParser.FILE_EXTENSAO)) {
                try {
                    importarConfigInputFile(new FileInputStream(file));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_file_not_found,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position)
    {
        File file = new File(folderList.get(position).getDirPath());
        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            showApagarPrompt(file);
        }
    }

    private void startMainListManager() {
        folderList = new ArrayList<>();
        fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        currentPath = null;
        pathAbertoPeloInicio = null;
        backDir = null;
        String[] listDirs = {
            HOME_PATH,
                HOME_PATH + "/ANON Injector",
                HOME_PATH + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents",
                HOME_PATH + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp.w4b/WhatsApp Business/Media/WhatsApp Business Documents",
            HOME_PATH + "/Download",
                HOME_PATH + "/Telegram/Telegram Documents",
                HOME_PATH + "/GBWhatsApp/Media/GBWhatsApp Documents",
                HOME_PATH + "/FMWhatsApp/Media/FMWhatsApp Documents",
                HOME_PATH + "/WhatsApp Business/Media/WhatsApp Business Documents",
                HOME_PATH + "/YOWhatsApp/Media/YOWhatsApp Documents",
                HOME_PATH + "/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents"

        };

        for (String dir : listDirs) {
            File file = new File(dir);

            if (file.exists() && !file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    String dir_name = file.getName();

                    if (dir.equals(HOME_PATH))
                        dir_name = getString(R.string.dir_home_name);

                    folderList.add(new ManagerFilesAdapter.ManagerItem(dir_name, file.getPath(), getString(R.string.dir_name)));
                }
            }

        }
        folderList.addAll(fileList);
        adapter = new ManagerFilesAdapter(this, folderList);
        rvManagerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        rvManagerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void fileManager(String folderPath) {
        if (folderPath == null || folderPath.equals(BACK_DIR)) {
            if (backDir != null && canGoBackFolder())
                folderPath = backDir.getPath();
            else {
                startMainListManager();
                return;
            }
        }
        folderList = new ArrayList<>();
        fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // está vindo do inicio
        if (currentPath == null) {
            pathAbertoPeloInicio = folderPath;
        }
        currentPath = folderPath;
        File path = new File(folderPath);
        if (path.getParentFile() != null && !currentPath.equals(pathAbertoPeloInicio)) {
            backDir = path.getParentFile();
        }
        
        for (File file : path.listFiles()) {
            if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    folderList.add(new ManagerFilesAdapter.ManagerItem(file.getName(), file.getPath(), getString(R.string.dir_name)));
                } else {
                    String file_extensao = getExtension(file);
                    if (file_extensao != null && file_extensao.equals(ConfigParser.FILE_EXTENSAO)) {
                        String dateLastModified = String.format("%s %s",
                            android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(this).format(file.lastModified()),
                                android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this).format(file.lastModified()));
                        
                        fileList.add(new ManagerFilesAdapter.ManagerItem(file.getName(), file.getPath(), dateLastModified));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(folderList);
        Collections.sort(fileList);
        folderList.addAll(fileList);

        // Adiciona a opção de voltar
        if (canGoBackFolder() || currentPath.equals(pathAbertoPeloInicio)) {
            folderList.add(0, new ManagerFilesAdapter.ManagerItem("..", BACK_DIR, folderPath));
        }

        adapter = new ManagerFilesAdapter(this, folderList);
        rvManagerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        rvManagerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (canGoBackFolder() || currentPath != null && currentPath.equals(pathAbertoPeloInicio)) {
            fileManager(BACK_DIR);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private boolean canGoBackFolder() {
        if (backDir != null) {
            return backDir.canRead() && !backDir.getPath().equals(currentPath);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void requestPermissionInfo() {
        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
            }
        } else {
            //below android 11
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 2296) {
            if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                    // perform action when allow permission success
                    startMainListManager();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Allow permission for storage access!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //fileManager(HOME_PATH);
                    startMainListManager();
                } else {
                    requestPermissionInfo();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    // Método chamado assim que o usuário concede ou nega uma permissão

    private boolean permissionGranted() {
        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
        } else {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        }
    }

    public String getExtension(File file) {
        String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();

        if (filename.contains(".")) {
            return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        }

        return "";
    }
    
    public void importarConfigInputFile(InputStream inputFile) {
        try {
            
            if (!ConfigParser.convertInputAndSave(inputFile, this)) {
                throw new IOException(getString(R.string.error_save_settings));
            }
            
            long mValidade = new Settings(this)
                .getPrefsPrivate().getLong(Settings.CONFIG_VALIDADE_KEY, 0);
            
            if (mValidade > 0) {
                SkStatus.logInfo(R.string.log_settings_valid,
                    android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(this).format(mValidade));
            }
            
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.success_import_settings, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                
            // atualiza views
            MainActivity.updateMainViews(this);
            
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        }
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Toolbar
    */
    
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private void setToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    
    private void showApagarPrompt(final File file) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .create();
        
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.title_delete_file);
            dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_delete_file));

            dialog.setButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
                {
                    if (file.delete())
                        fileManager(currentPath);
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_delete_file,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            dialog.setButton(dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2) {}
            });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

Android Manifest used in app

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.agn.injector">

    <!--Full network access-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!--View network connections-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!--Modify or delete the contents of your SD card-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <!--Read the contents of your SD card-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <!--Control vibration-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:resizeableActivity="true">
```

APK for demo:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/1ron5jzwyw9c0od/app-release.apk/file

Comment: Use Storage Access Framework to let the user pick the directory. After that list the files in it ..

Comment: @blackapps can you please help me by setting code

Comment: basically i have to pick file with .anon extention and export also